# What is the difference between "Author Rebuttal" and "Paper Discussion" in Academic Conferences?

Tags: peer-review, conference, computer-science, program-committee, chairing

In academic conferences and their important dates, I know what "Author Rebuttal Period" is but it is not particularly clear to me what is meant by "Paper Discussion Period"?

Are authors also involved in the discussion, or is it only between area chairs and fellow reviewers?

Comment: Which conference?

Comment: http://www.ieee-scam.org/2020/#call

Comment: Don't know about the specific venue, but usually it does not involve authors. The reviewers and chairs can take the rebuttal into account, discuss, and come to a decision.

Comment: Thanks. This particular venue does not have a period called "rebuttal", and I thought the discussion may involve some form of rebuttalling.

Comment: In that case, I think it's more likely that the "Reviews due Date" is an internal deadline for reviewers to submit their reviews, after which they would discuss in the "Paper Discussion" phase and then notify authors. But I am not sure. It is unlikely to involve a rebuttal since 4 days is too short to ask for a rebuttal, get it, discuss, and decide.

Comment: Please make your question more specific, by specifying field etc.. The way it is now it sounds like it does not apply to quite a few fields.

Comment: @user151413 It's tagged computer science.